# Ubuntu update problem

Tags: apt, updates

I`m trying to update & upgrade my current version of Ubuntu but I have some problems : 
When I run apt-get update i get the following errors :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/antonio.chiurazzi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/antonio.chiurazzi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I removed the sources from `var/lib/apt/lists` but I still receive the same error. Can anybody tell me what's happening and how i can remove that to successfully update my Ubuntu ?

My configuration : Ubuntu 12.10 on Intel I3 processor with 4gb DDR3 RAM.

Comment: it's a duplicate, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the GUI way to manage my software sources: system Settings --> software & updates and than under the other software tab uncheck the sources that cause problems. did you try this?